# Tooltip position

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip

I am working on a tooltip to show links and text. ( Basically a div of content)

The problem is my tooltip takes the table's row height, so verified it's parent's position(not set):
here is my css tooltip {

```
position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  background-color:#FFFCE0; box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);  color: #000000;
  }
```

I am changing the tooltip's top and left position dynamically using Javascript.

Any pointers or reference will help .

Thanks

Comment: What's the issue exactly? You say it's taking up the height, but there is no height set on your tooltip...and maybe there should be.

Comment: Try replicating the problem by adding the relevant code to stack snippet.

Comment: Unless you need to rewrite this for a particular reason here is a JQuery UI equivalent that will work on anything http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/ No point in rewriting something thats already been done before and is in use in many existing commercial applications.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36275678/how-to-create-a-tooltip